# Tikz-tree, label the roof

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I would like to label the roof of a tikz-tree. I tried to label it like a classical edge, but by unfortunately it is stuck to the right edge of the triangle. The tempory solution I'm using is to set the `pos=1`, and then using `below=Xcm`, but I need to manually set the `X` parameters, which is ugly.

Is there a better way to proceed, to put the label at for example 1/3 of the height of the triangle ?

Here is what I have when I give the same parameter for all roofs :

[image: result]

and my MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[labelRoof/.style={pos=1,below=0.3cm}]
    \Tree [.$A$ \edge[roof,fill=green] node[labelRoof]{$X$};{
      \Tree [.$B$ \edge[roof,fill=red] node[labelRoof]{$X$};{
        \Tree [.$C$ \edge[roof,fill=green] node[labelRoof]{$X$}; {~\quad~} ]
        \quad
        \Tree [.$D$ \edge[roof,fill=green] node[labelRoof]{$X$}; {~\quad~} ]}
      ]
      \quad
      \Tree [.$E$ \edge[roof,fill=red] node[labelRoof]{$X$};{
        \Tree [.$F$ \edge[roof,fill=green] node[labelRoof]{$X$}; {~\quad~} ]
        \quad
        \Tree [.$G$ \edge[roof,fill=green] node[labelRoof]{$X$}; {~\quad~} ]}
      ]} ]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An other method  consist of inserting the `node X` within the definition of   `\roof@edge@down` and the node appear every time roof edge is appealed

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}


\makeatletter
\def\roof@edge@down#1#2{(#1.south) -- (#2.north west) --node[anchor=base]{$X$} (#2.north east) -- cycle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \Tree [.$A$ \edge[roof,fill=green];{
      \Tree [.$B$ \edge[roof,fill=red];{
        \Tree [.$C$ \edge[roof,fill=green]; {~\quad~} ]
        \quad
        \Tree [.$D$ \edge[roof,fill=green]; {~\quad~} ]}
      ]
      \quad
      \Tree [.$E$ \edge[roof,fill=red];{
        \Tree [.$F$ \edge[roof,fill=green]; {~\quad~} ]
        \quad
        \Tree [.$G$ \edge[roof,fill=green]; {~\quad~} ]}
      ]} ]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 'You can have any label as long as it's `X`.'?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to improve on [Salim Bou](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/54817/salim-bou)'s answer... For reasons I don't understand, I was not able to use the `calc` tikz library and partway modifiers inside `\roof@edge@down`, but it still works fine.
The code below defines new keys you can use to customize the way the label is displayed:

- `roof label` to set the actual label, empty by default.
- `roof label pos` to set the position of the center of the label somewhere in between the top vertex and the bottom edge, defaults at 2/3 from the top vertex.
- `roof label fixed distance` to put the bottom of the text at a fixed distance above the bottom edge. Uses a default distance of `2pt` unless a distance is specified, see below. Defaults at `false`.
- `roof label distance` to customize the distance at which the label will be placed. Specifying some value will automatically set `roof label fixed distance` to `true`.

For several reasons, I personally prefer the "fixed distance" mode, but since your question was to put it at a relative distance, the default mode is "text center at 1/3 of the triangle height". Whichever mode you chose to use, just don't forget to provide a value to `roof label`at some point, or pgf/tikz will just write an empty string.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifRoofLabelFixedDist
\newif\ifTmpFixedDist
\tikzset{%% defining necessary keys with default values
  roof label fixed distance/.is if=RoofLabelFixedDist,
  @roof label distance/.store in=\myRoofLabelFixedDist,
  @roof label distance=2pt,
  roof label distance/.style={roof label fixed distance=true, @roof label distance={#1}},
  roof label/.store in=\myRoofLabel,
  roof label=,
  roof label pos/.store in=\myRoofLabelPos,
  roof label pos=.66,
}

\def\roof@edge@down#1#2{%
  \pgfextra{%% extracting key values for later use
    \global\let\tmpLabel\myRoofLabel
    \global\let\tmpPos\myRoofLabelPos
    \global\let\tmpDist\myRoofLabelFixedDist
    \ifRoofLabelFixedDist
      \global\TmpFixedDisttrue
    \else
      \global\TmpFixedDistfalse
    \fi
  }
  %% performing the normal operation?
  (#1.south) -- (#2.north west) -- (#2.north east) -- cycle ; %% <- the ";" clears custom keys
  \ifTmpFixedDist
    %% places the bottom of the text at "\tmpDist" above bottom edge
    \path (#2.north) +(0,\tmpDist) node [anchor=base] {\tmpLabel} -- (#1.south)
  \else
    %% places the center of the text at relative position \tmpPos between top vertex and bottom edge
    \path (#1.south) -- (#2.north) node [pos=\tmpPos,anchor=center] {\tmpLabel} -- (#1.south)
  \fi
  %% Note: the "-- (#1.south)" places pgf back to where it should have been after "(#1.south) -- (#2.north west) -- (#2.north east) -- cycle"
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[roof label=$X$] %% default value for everyone
    \Tree
    [.{custom label} \edge[roof,fill=green,roof label={snowflake}] ;
      {
        \Tree
        [.{fixed dist} \edge[roof,fill=red,roof label fixed distance] ;
          {
            \Tree [.$C$ \edge[roof,fill=green,roof label distance=10pt] ; {~\quad~} ]
            \quad
            \Tree [.$D$ \edge[roof,fill=green,roof label distance=0pt] ; {~\quad~} ]
          }
        ]
        \quad
        \Tree
        [.{rel pos} \edge[roof,fill=red] ;
          {
            \Tree [.$F$ \edge[roof,fill=green,roof label pos=0.4] ; {~\quad~} ]
            \quad
            \Tree [.$G$ \edge[roof,fill=green,roof label pos=0.7] ; {~\quad~} ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample image using custom keys to label the roof]

Just a note on the code in case you need to customize it: `\pgfextra{<code>}` is a way to tell pgf/tikz to suspend operation on the current path, do something else (typically computing some values), then resume execution on the path. I used it to bypass the fact that pgf/tikz reset its keys to default value in between each paths it processes. This makes the whole thing quite messy, but I don't know the data flow well enough to intercept the necessary information elsewhere...

Comment: (+1) Can you complete the code so it is a proper working example? (I.e. compiles.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Forest version:

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
  },
  Roofs and roofs,
  where level=1{
    edge+={fill=red},
  }{
    edge+={fill=green},
  },
  [A, roof label=\Gamma
    [B, roof label=\Delta
      [C, roof label=\Sigma
        [
        ]
      ]
      [D, roof label=\Theta
        [
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [E, roof label=\Psi
      [F, roof label=\Xi
        [
        ]
      ]
      [G, roof label=\Pi
        [
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: Roofs and roofs]

`Roofs and roofs` is a style which draws roofs throughout the tree. All edges are either a standard `roof` or a special `Roof` covering multiple children. `where level=1{...}{...}` determines the `fill` colour for nodes at level `1` (`red`) and everywhere else (`green`). `roof label=<maths>` puts a label, `$<maths>$`, in the `roof` or `Roof` beneath the current node.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\forestset{
  declare keylist={saved edge}{},
  Roof/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      delay={
        if level=0{
          tikz+/.process={OOw2}{edge}{edge label}{
            \draw [##1] (!1.parent first)--(.children)--(!l.parent last)--cycle ##2;
          },
        }{
          not ignore edge,
          edge/.option=saved edge,
          edge path'={
            (!1.parent first)--(.children)--(!l.parent last)--cycle
          },
        },
      },
      for children={
        saved edge/.option=edge,
        no edge,
      },
    },
  },
  Roofs and roofs/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      where content={}{
        content={\smash{\phantom{A}}},
      }{},
    },
    where n children<=1{
      roof,
    }{
      Roof,
    },
  },
  roof label/.style={
    if n children=1{
      !1.edge label={node [midway,above] {$#1$}},
    }{
      edge label={node [midway,above] {$#1$}},
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    math content,
  },
  Roofs and roofs,
  where level=1{
    edge+={fill=red},
  }{
    edge+={fill=green},
  },
  [A, roof label=\Gamma
    [B, roof label=\Delta
      [C, roof label=\Sigma
        [
        ]
      ]
      [D, roof label=\Theta
        [
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [E, roof label=\Psi
      [F, roof label=\Xi
        [
        ]
      ]
      [G, roof label=\Pi
        [
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```